# How to determine which Child Page is being displayed from Master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm writing code on the master page, and I need to know which child (content) page is being displayed.  How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a bad idea to start with. The idea of the master is that it shouldn't care what page is there as this is all common code for each page.

Comment: +1 Exactly.  This very much goes against what a master page is about.

Comment: This is a good general rule, but how about something like a breadcrumb?  You want it on every page, but you need to know what specific page is loaded to determine the crumbs.  For this I typically expose a public function on the masterpage for setting the final crumb, this is called by the page.  The other crumbs are determined by the sitemap.

Comment: What would your recommendation be if your master page contained logic to redirect to a 'safe' page under certain circumstances UNLESS the safe page was being displayed?

Comment: @norbertB gives a pretty good solution IMO on how to accomplish the desired outcome without having the master page needing to know what page is being displayed.

Comment: So, what if I wanted an image slider only on my landing page, and no-where else? (and my ContentPlaceHolder is wrapped in a div with a generic style, which the image slider shouldn't have)

Comment: I find the best answers to "how" questions are always "no"

Comment: This is a super old answer, with new Meta tags handling all social media content, this is a good idea to have default meta tags on the master page and the page specific tags on each other page if necessary

Answer (score 32):

I use this:

```
string pageName = this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().FullName;
```

It retuns the class name in this format "ASP.default_aspx", but I find that easy to parse for most purposes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can use `string pageName = this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().BaseType.Name;` This returns base class type of child page. For most cases it gives the Page Adress without "aspx" tag. For example "Default".

Answer (score 24):

It's better to let the `ContentPage` notify the `MasterPage`. That's why the `ContentPage` has a `Master` Property and `MasterPage` does not have `Child` property.
Best pratice in this is to define a property or method on the `MasterPage` and use this through the `Master` property of the `ContentPage`.

If you use this technique it's best to explicitly specify  the classname for the MasterPage. This makes to use the MasterPage in the ContentPage.

Example:

```
//Page_Load
MyMaster m = (MyMaster)this.Master;

m.TellMasterWhoIAm(this);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this.  Sometimes the master page *does* need a little bit of information from its users.  This is a clean way to do it.

Comment: This is a good solution to the question. What the original poster was asking how to do wasn't really a good practice to follow, and you gave an solution that directed the OP to following a better practice. Thanks @norbertB!

Comment: Here's a reminder for myself and other forgetful souls. For Norbert's answer to work, be sure to add [@ MasterType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228274(v=vs.100)) directives to the child Web Forms' **.aspx** files so that the C# code can access the master's properties and methods like `Master.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";`

Answer (score 9):

I have had a reason to check the child page in the master page.

I have all my menu options on my master page and they need to be disabled if certain system settings are not set up.

If they are not then a message is displayed and the buttons are disabled. As the settings page  is a content page from this master page I don't want the message to keep being displayed on all the settings pages.

this code worked for me:

```
                //Only show the message if on the dashboard (first page after login)
                if (this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page is Dashboard)
                {
                    //Show modal message box
                    mmb.Show("Warning Message");
                }
```

Comment: I am using VB and this works for me: If ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().BaseType Is GetType(Dashboard)

Answer (score 7):

Use the Below code.

```
Page.ToString().Replace("ASP.","").Replace("_",".")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. its worked. İt means, we can reach to any page from  masterpage...

Comment: this was my solution, i needed the name of the content page to evaluate a funcion that should or shouldn't show a label

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

[Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.currentexecutionfilepath(loband).aspx)

Comment: This did the job in my case as I was asking for the precise file name, not the object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to the problem (this code goes into the code behind the master page):

```
if (Page.TemplateControl.AppRelativeVirtualPath == "~/YourPageName.aspx")
{
   // your code here
}
```

or a bit more sophisticated, but less readable:

```
if (Page.TemplateControl.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Equals("~/YourPageName.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;
```

or

```
Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this in a project of mine to dynamically attach css files based on the page being loaded.  I just get the name of the file from the request:

```
this.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

And then extract the file name from there.  I'm not sure if this will work if you are doing URL re-writes though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the last segmant or the request and I'll be the Form name

```
string pageName = this.Request.Url.Segments.Last(); 

if (pageName.Contains("EmployeeTermination.aspx"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

`<%: this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().Name.Split('_')[0].ToUpper() %>`

Put that code within the `title` tags of the `Site.Master`

Answer (score 0):

```
string s =   Page.ToString().Replace("ASP.directory_name_","").Replace("_aspx",".aspx").Replace("_","-");
        if (s == "default.aspx")
              { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

so many answers I am using

```
<%if(this.MainContent.Page.Title != "mypagetitle") { %>
<%}%>
```

this makes it easy to exclude any single page and since your comparing a string you could even prefix pages like exclude_pagetitle and comparing a sub-string of the title. I use this commonly to exclude log in pages from certain features I don't want to load like session timeouts and live chat.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked like a charmed ..try it

```
string PName = Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Length - 1];
```

Answer (score -2):

Page.Request.Url.PathAndQuery or one of the other properties of the Url Uri object should be available to you from the master page code.

Answer (score -4):

You can check the page type in the code-behind:

```
// Assuming MyPage1, MyPage2, and MyPage3 are the class names in your aspx.cs files:

if (this.Page is MyPage1)
{
  // do MyPage1 specific stuff
}
else if (this.Page is MyPage2)
{
  // do MyPage2 specific stuff
}
else if (this.Page is MyPage3)
{
  // do MyPage3 specific stuff
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd expect too, but this doesn't work. ASP.NET seems to mangle the class declarations (annoyingly!) so while it looks like you're declaring `MyPage1`, you're actually not. You get something like `ASP.MyPage1_aspx`, and you can't refer to this type at compile time.