# Master pages -- Getting calling page name

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

Can someone tell me how to get the name of the child page being called in a Master page scenario. For example, if I have the following masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

And I create a page called Test.aspx which inherits this masterpage, how can I, from the masterpage, know that Test.aspx has been requested (since this masterpage can be inherited by more then 1 aspx page)?

Comment: What's the end goal? There might be a better method to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with your comments, I see a couple of options:

1) In your login page, on a non-postback, check the Referrer - this will be the page that sent you to the login page ([Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)), store that in session for the postback of their login details, and then send the user back.

2) Use the [standard features of ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx) to handle login/redirections (which basically use the same system as 1).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269050/c-asp-net-how-to-determine-which-child-page-is-being-displayed-from-master-page) to what you're asking, but I would pay attention to the accepted answer, trying to figure out the child page from the master page is probably not a good design idea.

Comment: Well actually, what I'm trying to do is not change anything on either pages. What I want to do in the master page is check for a session variable, which holds login info, and if the variable is not set, I wanted to redirect to a login page. I wanted to page a RefPage variable in my querystring though that holds the URL of the previous page, that way, after the user logs in, I can refer them back to the original page

Answer (score 1):

I would notify in the other direction. Add properties to your master page then set them from the content pages.

In your master:

```
public partial class PortalMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    public string PageSection { get; set; }
}
```

In your .aspx add this directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="PortalMaster.master" %>
```

Then in your .aspx.cs set the property value like so:

```
Master.PageSection = "about";
```

Comment: Well actually, what I'm trying to do is not change anything on either pages. What I want to do in the master page is check for a session variable, which holds login info, and if the variable is not set, I wanted to redirect to a login page. I wanted to page a RefPage variable in my querystring though that holds the URL of the previous page, that way, after the user logs in, I can refer them back to the original page

Comment: On your log in page, check for Request.UrlReferrer. If it has a value (not null), store it in a hidden input, then redirect after log in. No querystring needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "Page" member of the masterpage

Answer (score 0):

From the codebehind in the MasterPage, the `Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath` property will tell you the path.