# How to force the user to change his password after first login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authentication, change-password

I want to force the user to change his password after his first login. Now, where should I put the *redirection code* to ChangePassword page  ?

- If I put it in the `Page_Load` of Default page, user can move to any page because he **is Authenticated**.
- If I put it in the `Page_Load` of Master page, the ChangePassword page uses the same master page, and it'll enter in an infinit loop of redirections.

  I though of ignoring the redirection if the `Page` is the ChagePassword page from the Master page, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269050/how-to-determine-which-child-page-is-being-displayed-from-master-page/269153#269153) answer which says:

  > This sounds like a bad idea to start with. The idea of the master is that it shouldn't care what page is there as this is all common code for each page.

Any suggestion!

Comment: interesting question. It would be good if this feature is added to ASP.NET web security module.

Comment: I guess I would make a Base class for my pages (to avoid doing that stuff in the master) and in OnInit: if(auth && !User.HasChangedPassword && typeof(Page) != typeof(ChangePasswordPage)) Response.Redirect(... (I haven't try the typeof test but you can test the request.url if it do not work)

Answer (score 5):

Here you are, a fully tested solution ;)

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /****note: UserName and Password are textbox fields****/

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(UserName.Text);
        if (user == null)
        {
           FailureText.Text = "Invalid username. Please try again.";
           return;
        }
        if (user.IsLockedOut)
           user.UnlockUser();

        /* this is the interesting part for you */
        if (user.LastPasswordChangedDate == user.CreationDate) //if true, that means user never changed their password before
        {
            //TODO: add your change password logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly modified version to account for db save times.                                                           `var timeSpan = user.LastPasswordChangedDate - user.CreationDate;`  `if (timeSpan.Minutes < 1)`

Comment: Will this prevent accessing app resources directly?

Comment: @Filip, no it will not, and because of that on it's own merit it's not a very good advise ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in GLobal.asax file.

Check if user in logged in and request url is not ChangePassword then redirect to change password page.

```
/// <summary>
/// this event occurs just after user is authenticated
/// </summary>
void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if user is authenticated
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // checking page extension
        switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower()))
        {
            case ".bmp":
            case ".gif":
            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpe":
            case ".jpeg":
            case ".png":
            case ".css":
            case ".js":
            case ".txt":
            case ".swf":
                // don't redirect, these requests may required in many cases
                break;
            default:
                // checking if request is not for ChangePassword.aspx page
                if (!Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("/changepassword.aspx"))
                {
                    Context.Response.Redirect("~/ChangePassword.aspx");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach won't work if user when logs in, accesses urls directly. Correct? We first on first login, but he is free to change the url and access pages without really changing password?

Answer (score 1):

We had an app with similar requirements.  We extended the base ASP.NET membership provider to allow for a check on the LastPasswordChangedDate and compared it to the CreateDate.  If equal, that means the user has never changed their password, and was redirected to the login page.

I see you would like to have some kind of check to keep bugging them even after the login.  I think you can accomplish this in the AuthorizationRequest of the Global.asax.  That might be expensive though.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle the following events of the Login control,

•LoggedIn 
•LoggingIn

Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that the user is **Authenticated**, so he can move to anywhere.

Comment: Ok, I got it you mean if he moves before changing the password, then you should put it in the Page_Load of the master page and check the Request.Url and if it is not the ChangePassword page url then you redirect thus you break the recursive.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you should put the validation code in "Page_PreRender"

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Validation Code       
}
```

this event will fire the code before the page renders anything

Comment: What happens when the page is attempting to update the database, or something like that, and fails during and earlier part of the page's lifecycle? The user would never know as they would be sent off to the ChangePassword page.

Answer (score 0):

Which object are you putting into the section in order to evaluate if the user is authenticated? I would just set a boolean property named "ChangePasswordOnNextLoggin", then if its true I redirect to "ChangePassword.aspx", you may put it wherever you want (even in the master page, as you only redirect if this property is true, avoiding the infinite loop).

But personally I would make a wrapper for the PAGE object, that every .aspx code behind class should inherit, then I would inherit this wrapper instead, on the wrapper ctor I would add an Authenticate method to the Load event in such a way it would be the first method to be called when any page is loaded. If I do it, i'm able to avoid putting validation code on MasterPage and the code behind, making the code cleaner. Do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

In the place of your code where the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the user to change his password on the very first login, after registration, you just create one more field in your database's login table which will have a status value whether the initial pasword change process has been done. So when a user logs in the first time, that value is checked and, if it is something like "unchanged," redirect the user from the login page to the change password page. Upon successful password change, update the field.

Comment: Did you write this answer on your phone ?

Answer (score -2):

In SQL Server 2005(plus VS2008), Apart from all the "add one more field" approaches, I think it's much easier to execute asp.net security database's built in stored procedure `aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByName`. It returns a dataset with all the info you'll ever need incl last activity date, last password change date, last login date etc with time values.